# How does android scale gesture works?

Tags: android, android-gesture

In the ScaleGesture how android calculate the scale factor in `detector.getScaleFactor();` and in which range?

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

                // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
                mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 15.0f));
                _renderer.z=-mScaleFactor;
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for pinch you will find the same formula basically and according to the source code:

```
mScaleFactor = getCurrentSpan() / getPreviousSpan();
```

It's the distance of the current pinch divided by the first/old pinch.

Comment: this is not working on android 6.0 
See my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594539/scalegesturedetector-getscalefactor-always-returning-1-0-in-android-6-0